# Can I replace a 4 wire ballast with a 5 wire one?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Can I replace a 4 wire ballast with a 5 wire one?

The new ballast has an extra blue wire.

Comment: Instead, get rid of the ballast and replace the old fluorescent lamp with a more efficient, longer lasting LED lamp.

Comment: Probably not.  Shoot us a picture of the wiring diagram on the old ballast, and we can advise.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring diagrams on the old and new ballasts?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that yes, you can. The 5 wire is simply a newer, safer design for a ballast. 
However, should you? Unless you are working on one ballast in a large system, it may be wiser to upgrade to LED technology and solder/cone new fixtures into your workspace, then you'll never have to deal with those darn ballasts again!

Useful Diagram: http://www.electrical101.com/ballast-diagrams.html

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeRkLdrMwqQ
(Unsure as to how accurate this may be, there are other online resources as well)

**Disclaimer**
I am *not* an electrician nor do I pretend to be one. I do a fair amount of DIY projects and home improvement but am not a professional!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!